# Specify RequiredCreationPolicy for non-Attributed Imports

Tags: c#-4.0, inversion-of-control, mef

I have an IoC wrapper that uses MEF as it's DI container, an applicable snippet of the wrapper is shown below.

```
public static bool TryGetComponent<T>(out T component) 
{
    CompositionContainer container = RetrieveContainer();

    T retrievedComponent = container.GetExportedValueOrDefault<T>();
    if (retrievedComponent.Equals(default(T)))
    {
        component = default(T);
        return false;
    }

    component = retrievedComponent;

    return true;
}
```

Most of the exported components in the CompositionContainer specify a CreationPolicy of "Any".

```
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Any)]
```

For types that I create I can easily use the following import attribute to get MEF to serve the exported types as NonShared instances.

```
[Import(RequiredCreationPolicy = CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
```

However, since my IoC wrapper must also be used by classes that do not use MEF or any of its Import attributes and must use my IoC API to obtain instances exported types. **I need a way to specify the CreationPolicy when I programmatically use the CompositionContainer to GetExports and GetExportedValues**. Is this even possible without using import attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to query the container exactly like as if you had a ImportAttribute with RequiredCreationPolicy=NonShared then try creating your own custom [ContractBasedImportDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388337.aspx). One of the parameters for to the contructor is a CreationPolicy that represents the required creation policy. 
Something like:

```
container.GetExports(new ContractBasedImportDefinition(
    AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(type),
    AttributedModelServices.GetTypeIdentity(type),
    null,
    ImportCardinality.ZeroOrMore,
    false,
    false,
    CreationPolicy.NonShared));
```

Of course you can adjust the parameters as necessary but this will get you moving in the right direction and will cause the container to create NonShared versions of any part that is marked as Any (which is the default).

Comment: Thanks Wes, this does exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `CreationPolicy` is passed as part of a component's metadata. This means, you should be able to query the metadata for the part, and see if it exists. The way `CreationPolicy` is specified in metadata is to use the full type name `System.ComponentModel.Composition.CreationPolicy` as the key, and the enum result as the value. So, knowing this we can build an extension method:

```
public static T GetExportedValueOrDefault<T>(this CompositionContainer container, CreationPolicy creationPolicy)
{
  var metadataKey = typeof(CreationPolicy).FullName;

  var lazy = container.GetExportedValueOrDefault<T, IDictionary<string, object>>();
  if (lazy == null)
    return default(T);

  if (lazy.Metadata.ContainsKey(metadataKey))
  {
    // If the creation policy matches the required, return.
    if (((CreationPolicy)lazy.Metadata[metadataKey]) == creationPolicy) 
      return lazy.Value;
  }
  else
  {
    // Return the value as we assume it satisfies the default CreationPolicy = Any
    return lazy.Value; 
  }

  return default(T);
}
```

Now, firstly we create our expected key, and then we grab a `Lazy<T, TMetadata>` instance which includes the type and any associated metadata as a `Lazy<T, IDictionary<string, object>>` instance. If the lazy comes back as `null`, we can fail early because there were no matching parts at all.

Next, we can check the metadata dictionary `Lazy.Metadata` to determine if the metadata exists. If it does, we need to cast and compare against our chosen metadata. If that succeeds, return our part instance.

If that doesn't succeed (e.g., if the part is using the implicit `CreationPolicy` of `Any` [i.e., the `PartCreationPolicyAttribute` is omitted from the export]), we'll assume that the part can be returned, as we can match on the default `Any` creation policy, so we can match both `NonShared` and `Shared` parts.

You should be able to use this in place of the normal `GetExportedValueOrDefault<T>` call:

```
T retrievedComponent = container.GetExportedValueOrDefault<T>(CreationPolicy.NonShared);
```

Comment: Matthew, thanks for the quick response. What you have presented looked promissing but I don't think it works as one would expect.

The default 'CreationPolicy' is actually 'Any', this is what MEF uses when no PartCreationPolicy is specified on an export. However, when no RequiredCreationPolicy is specified on an import then MEF defaults to using 'Shared'.
So the issue would be, when I call 'container.GetExportedValueOrDefault<T>(CreationPolicy.NonShared)' there will be no metadata match and no part will be retured, even when the export did NOT specify 'Shared'; not the expected behavior.

Comment: @Steve - Ah, I did not know that [likely getting RequiredCreationPolicy and PartCreationPolicy behaviours confused]. Will update.

Comment: @Steve - Does that work better? Updated to assume `Any` and will satisfy any part where no metadata is provided?

Comment: Matthew, Thanks for the update. This certainly returns a value when the RequiredCreationPolicy is NonShared and the PartCreationPolicy is Any, however, what I'm realizing is that there is more work to be done to get this API to behave like an Import attribute specifying a RequiredCreationPolicy of NonShared:

When the PartCreationPolicy is Any, some callers may want to share an instance and some may not. The ones that want to share should all get the same instance (keep a reference to Lazy<T> and always use its Value). For all other callers a new Lazy<T> must be used each time.

Comment: Matthew, another issue I've realized will occur is that objects using an Import attribute with a RequiredCreationPolicy of Shared, will not the get same shared instance as objects calling this extension method and specifying a CreationPolicy of Shared. Since MEF will be using its own shared internal Lazy<T> instance and the extension method will be using a distinct shared Lazy<T> instance.